# PostgreSQL parametrized query

Tags: sql, postgresql, parameters, plpgsql, reusability

I often do need to submit pretty much the same query but with different parameter (single parameter but multiple times within `SELECT …` clause (not `WHERE`(!))).

To illustrate, it's in every place where `duc.opt_level >= 5 /*v_min_level*/` occurs within below:

```
SELECT duc.id_du, duc.du_type_cd, duc.du_name, duc.du_addr, duc.id_du_def, duc.def_repeat_flg, defc.allows_txt_flg
  ,r.lvl + CASE duc.du_type_cd WHEN 'e' THEN CASE WHEN duc.opt_level >= 5 /*v_min_level*/ AND duc.max_occurs=1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ELSE 0 END lvl
  ,CASE duc.du_type_cd WHEN 'e' THEN CASE WHEN duc.opt_level >= 5 /*v_min_level*/ AND duc.max_occurs=1 THEN r.id_du ELSE duc.id_du END ELSE r.id_du END entid
  ,CASE duc.du_type_cd WHEN 'e' THEN CASE WHEN duc.opt_level >= 5 /*v_min_level*/ AND duc.max_occurs=1 THEN r.entraw ELSE duc.du_addr END ELSE r.entraw END entraw
  ,CASE duc.du_type_cd WHEN 'e' THEN CASE WHEN duc.opt_level >= 5 /*v_min_level*/ AND duc.max_occurs=1 THEN r.entnm ELSE duc.du_name END ELSE r.entnm END entnm
  ,CASE duc.du_type_cd WHEN 'e' THEN CASE WHEN duc.opt_level >= 5 /*v_min_level*/ AND duc.max_occurs=1 THEN r.pentid ELSE r.entid END ELSE r.pentid END pentid
  ,CASE duc.du_type_cd WHEN 'e' THEN CASE WHEN duc.opt_level >= 5 /*v_min_level*/ AND duc.max_occurs=1 THEN r.pentraw ELSE r.entraw END ELSE r.pentraw END pentraw
  ,CASE duc.du_type_cd WHEN 'e' THEN CASE WHEN duc.opt_level >= 5 /*v_min_level*/ AND duc.max_occurs=1 THEN r.pentnm ELSE r.entnm END ELSE r.pentnm END pentnm
  ,defc.def_type, defc.val_type
  ,defc.is_nillable
  ,defc.optional
FROM r
JOIN data_unit duc
  ON duc.id_parent_du = r.id_du
JOIN du_def defc
  ON defc.id_du_def = duc.id_du_def
```

…

Postgres ver. 9.5.1

Any elegant way of parameterizing this query so I can use call it simply only by redefining this parameter?

Something along the lines of *anonymous PL/pgSQL block* comes to mind but I don't know exactly how

Comment: Seems to ma that the nested CASE can be avoided.

Comment: Stored function or [PREPARE/EXECUTE statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html) for example.

Comment: @joop how? do you mean to rewrite `CASE … WHEN` to `CASE WHEN …`?

Comment: @Abelisto with PREPARE/EXECUTE I'm afraid it requires me to put lot of `?` and then call with multiple but same parameters: `execute pblock(5,5,5,5,5,5,…)`

Comment: Yes: `CASE WHEN duc.du_type_cd = 'e' AND duc.opt_level < 5 AND duc.max_occurs <> 1 THEN duc.id_du ELSE r.id_du END entid` ... etc.  (assuming NOT NULL)

Comment: No, just use `$1` inside query several times, fe: `select $1, $1 || $1 ...`

Comment: Please post a *complete* query and always your version of Postgres. There's probably an even better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can cross join to a "values" table:

```
SELECT duc.id_du, duc.du_type_cd, duc.du_name, duc.du_addr, duc.id_du_def, duc.def_repeat_flg, defc.allows_txt_flg
      ,r.lvl +  
         CASE duc.du_type_cd WHEN 'e' THEN CASE WHEN duc.opt_level >= p.min_level AND duc.max_occurs=1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ELSE 0 END lvl
      ,CASE duc.du_type_cd WHEN 'e' THEN CASE WHEN duc.opt_level >= p.min_level AND duc.max_occurs=1 THEN r.id_du ELSE duc.id_du END ELSE r.id_du END entid
      ,CASE duc.du_type_cd WHEN 'e' THEN CASE WHEN duc.opt_level >= p.min_level AND duc.max_occurs=1 THEN r.entraw ELSE duc.du_addr END ELSE r.entraw END entraw
      ,CASE duc.du_type_cd WHEN 'e' THEN CASE WHEN duc.opt_level >= p.min_level AND duc.max_occurs=1 THEN r.entnm ELSE duc.du_name END ELSE r.entnm END entnm
      ,CASE duc.du_type_cd WHEN 'e' THEN CASE WHEN duc.opt_level >= p.min_level AND duc.max_occurs=1 THEN r.pentid ELSE r.entid END ELSE r.pentid END pentid
      ,CASE duc.du_type_cd WHEN 'e' THEN CASE WHEN duc.opt_level >= p.min_level AND duc.max_occurs=1 THEN r.pentraw ELSE r.entraw END ELSE r.pentraw END pentraw
      ,CASE duc.du_type_cd WHEN 'e' THEN CASE WHEN duc.opt_level >= p.min_level AND duc.max_occurs=1 THEN r.pentnm ELSE r.entnm END ELSE r.pentnm END pentnm
      ,defc.def_type, defc.val_type
      ,defc.is_nillable
      ,defc.optional
FROM ...
  cross join (values (5)) as p(min_level)
```

Comment: Does it not affect performance? (I know it's single-row dummy inline table but still…)

Comment: I would be **very** surprised if that made any difference in the performance. But if you want to make sure, check the output of `explain analyze`

Answer (score 0):

***Assuming*** all columns cannot be NULL (information missing in the question).

Your task becomes a lot simpler after untangling the `CASE` expressions to:

```
 , CASE WHEN duc.du_type_cd = 'e' AND (duc.opt_level < 5 OR duc.max_occurs <> 1) THEN r.lvl + 1   ELSE r.lvl     END AS lvl
 , CASE WHEN duc.du_type_cd = 'e' AND (duc.opt_level < 5 OR duc.max_occurs <> 1) THEN duc.id_du   ELSE r.id_du   END AS entid
 , CASE WHEN duc.du_type_cd = 'e' AND (duc.opt_level < 5 OR duc.max_occurs <> 1) THEN duc.du_addr ELSE r.entraw  END AS entraw
  -- etc.
```

The same, repeated conditions can be concentrated in a single `LEFT JOIN` to another instance of `r` (`r1`) in the `FROM` list. Then default to alternative values with `COALESCE` if the conditions are not met:

```
SELECT duc.id_du, duc.du_type_cd, duc.du_name, duc.du_addr, duc.id_du_def, duc.def_repeat_flg
     , defc.allows_txt_flg, defc.def_type, defc.val_type, defc.is_nillable, defc.optional
     , COALESCE(r1.lvl    , r.lvl + 1)   AS lvl
     , COALESCE(r1.id_du  , duc.id_du)   AS entid
     , COALESCE(r1.entraw , duc.du_addr) AS entraw
     , COALESCE(r1.entnm  , duc.du_name) AS entnm
     , COALESCE(r1.pentid , r.entid)     AS pentid
     , COALESCE(r1.pentraw, r.entraw)    AS pentraw
     , COALESCE(r1.pentnm , r.entnm)     AS pentnm
FROM   duc
JOIN   defc ON ???  -- missing information
JOIN   r    ON ???  -- missing information
LEFT   JOIN r1 ON duc.du_type_cd <> 'e'
               OR (duc.opt_level >= 5 /*v_min_level*/ AND duc.max_occurs = 1);
```

Now you provide *`v_min_level`* only once. And the query is much shorter. May be a bit faster, too.

And never omit the keyword `AS` for column aliase. [The manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html#AEN87606)

> **Omitting the `AS` Key Word**
>   ...
>   In `FROM` items, both the standard and PostgreSQL allow `AS` to be omitted
>   before an alias that is an unreserved keyword. But this is impractical
>   for output column names, because of syntactic ambiguities.

Comment: Interesting approach. I suppose I'm looking at handling it in the context of PostgreSQL specific syntax/features (like. aforementioned `PREPARE/EXECUTE`) rather than rewriting the specific query. I don't see the point of sacrificing readability and performance (extra LEFT OUTER JOINS) for having single substitution placeholder. In this particular (hierarchical) query (updated) I think it's an overkill if at all possible.
re. `AS` in aliases - agree, that's the good practice but to be consistent all SQL queries should always quote their table and column names to be 100% safe, don't they ;) ?

Comment: @msciwoj: [About quoted identifiers.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860) As for performance: it remains to be seen which approach is faster. The join condition is evaluated *once* per row, while your `CASE` expressions are evaluated for every column- depends on how many you have. And if there's an index to support the expressions, the join may be substantially faster. Just test with `explain analyze`. Of course you can use prepared statements or functions with parameters. There are many related answers here on SO.